# Memory leak by setting tableview background

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Did a test on instrument and found memory leak for this piece of code for my iphone (IOS 4.1), but does not have memory leak when run on simulator (IOS 4.3) :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];    
    [self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView;
    [backgroundView release];
    backgroundView = nil;
}
```

Instrument show [UIColor allocWithZone] responsible for the memory leak.

Is this a bug of IOS 4.1 or mistake from my code? Should I ignore this if this belongs to UIKit memory leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a leak in your code. UIKit might be allocating some one time memory for the first time initialization.

Comment: But, Instrument show memory leaking for this part of code? Is that ok to ignore this? Thanks

Comment: @TonyMocha Is the memory leak only happening on the simulator or the device too?  The device is all that matters for leaks.

Comment: I would ignore it if it is an isolated incident. If you are really concerned or observe memory growth then you can report it to Apple.

Comment: It happens on devise (IOS4.1), but not on Simulator (IOS 4.3). Will ignore this, will update this thread if there's issue. Thanks